# Display Author name PHP (Selfmade Plug-IN)

Tags: plugins, php, author

I have a problem for which I need help, because I just can not find a solution myself.

I have taken over a site where a selfmade plugin was created by someone before..
Using the default plug-in „Contact Form 7“, people can create posts on the page. ( https://gyazo.com/c8b20adecacd90fb9bfe72ad2138a980 )
About the self-created plug-in „Contact Form 7 extender“, the post is generated in the background via a PHP code. (https://gyazo.com/115a6c7c9afafd2970b66fd421ca76a3)

This is how it should work:
If a user is not logged in, the author becomes „Hyperspace_Bot“.
If a user is logged in, the Author name of the user is displayed.

Now the problem:
When a user who is logged in creates a post via the contact form, no Author is displayed….
(https://gyazo.com/b51653a1c5fc08b875a50b926c7565d3)
(https://gyazo.com/54e4067ecf1227831898a79e1577affa)
As you can see on the screenshots again, there is no author entered. Currently I always have to enter them manually afterwards.

Here is the important part of the code of the plug-in:

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'createPostData' );

function createPostData() {
     //get user id
     //$user = get_userdatabylogin('myusername');
     //$user = get_user_by('login', $user_login);
     //$udi = $user->ID;

     get_currentuserinfo();

     if ($_POST['aut'] == '') {
             // Create post object
             $my_post = array(
                     'post_title' => $_POST['title'],
                     'post_content' => $_POST['Description'],
                     'post_status' => 'pending',
                     'post_author' => 3,
                     'post_category' => array($_POST['postcategory'])
             );
     } else {
             $my_post = array(
                     'post_title' => $_POST['title'],
                     'post_content' => $_POST['Description'],
                     'post_status' => 'publish',
                     //'post_author' => $user,
                     'post_author' => $user_ID,
                     'post_category' => array($_POST['postcategory'])
             );
     }
```

The problem is with ‚post_author‘ => $User_ID in the second part I think…. I’ve already tried different ways with get_current_user_id() or $author_id = get_the_author_meta( ‚ID‘ ), but can’t find a solution.

If someone has an idea, I would be very grateful!

Thanks a lot in advance.

Best regards
Fabian

Whole plugin:
https://pastebin.com/8RFRPRLw

Comment: Your Code is a security nightmare... Right now its super easy to hijack the website. I strongly advise to use a Plugin like https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/

Comment: You probably need to change the `if ($_POST['aut'] == '')` condition too. What's that trying to check?

Comment: i think this checks if the user is logged in, so has a rank like subscriber, editor, author or if he is not logged in and has no rank. If he is not logged in the author name becomes "Hyperspace_bot".

Comment: I think this bit specifically checks if the posted form has a non empty field ‘aut’. If you want to check if the user is logged in you can test the result of get_current_user_id() or is_logged_in().

Comment: I’m curious: how? There’s probably ways to make posts but I’m not sure you can do worse than that.

Comment: hmm yes, that makes sense! But how does the code then recognize currently a user is registered (logged in) / has an author name or is not registered and becomes hyperspace_bot? Because that currently still works wonderfully

Answer (score 0):

Your `$my_post` array contains `'post_author' => $user_ID`, but `$user_ID` isn't defined.

According to [WP codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_currentuserinfo/), `get_currentuserinfo` is deprecated, and should be replaced with `wp_get_current_user`. But in this case you want the ID, so a better option would be `get_current_user_id`

So if you replace this line:

```
get_currentuserinfo();
```

With:

```
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
```

You should be in business.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for the answer! I tried it (I think before also so similar). But it still does not work :(, it just does not take the author name from the logged in user

Comment: I don't see anywhere that needs the author name?

Comment: Hi, the author's name is not entered manually. People who are registered on the site get the status "Author" and have their name and all their data stored as a profile / user. This data from the logged in user, more precisely only the name, I want to have automatically in the post as can be seen in the screenshots. But currently the code does not seem to find the name of the person who sends the post.